# Retrieve multiple rows using DATE BETWEEN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, between, date-comparison

I have the below table structure.

```
ID   |   FromDate   |    ToDate
1    |  2020-01-02  |  2020-06-01
2    |  2020-08-01  |  2020-12-01
3    |  2020-01-02  |  2020-11-28
4    |  2020-04-01  |  2020-05-28
```

When I pass 2 input parameters named `fromDate` and `toDate`, it should select the relevant records.

E.g. If `FromDate = 2020-01-01` and `ToDate = 2020-06-01`, it should return records with IDs 1 and 4 since those two records are between the dates as the parameters supplied.

I am using the below method at the moment and I feel like it's wasting a lot of resources.

```
AND ToDate IN (select * from 
(select adddate('2000-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6                 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2021-01-02 00:00:00' and '2022-03-02 00:00:00') ORDER BY name ASC,lt.ID ASC<code>
```

**Is there any other way to achieve this task?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table_name where fromDate>'2020-xx-xx' AND ToDate<'2020-xx-xx';
```

this query format can get records between insertion dates

Comment: Thanks. I stuck with BETWEEN and completely forgot this. 